# Speeding up dplyr pipe including checks with mutate_if and if_else on larger tables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I wrote some code to performed oversampling, meaning that I replicate my observations in a data.frame and add noise to the replicates, so they are not exactly the same anymore. I'm quite happy that it works now as intended, but...it is too slow. I'm just learning dplyr and have no clue about data.table, but I hope there is a way to improve my function. I'm running this code in a function for 100s of data.frames which may contain about 10,000 columns and 400 rows.

This is some toy data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

train_set1 <- rep(0, 300)
train_set2 <- rep("Factor1", 300)
train_set3 <- data.frame(replicate(1000, sample(0:1, 300, rep = TRUE)))
train_set <- cbind(train_set1, train_set2, train_set3)
row.names(train_set) <- c(paste("Sample", c(1:nrow(train_set)), sep = "_"))
```

This is the code to replicate each row a given number of times and a function to determine whether the added noise later will be positive or negative:

```r
# replicate each row twice, added row.names contain a "."
train_oversampled <- train_set[rep(seq_len(nrow(train_set)), each = 3), ]

# create a flip function
flip <- function() {
  sample(c(-1,1), 1)
}
```

In the relevant "too slow" piece of code, I'm subsetting the row.names for the added "." to filter for the replicates. Than I select only the numeric columns. I go through those columns row by row and leave the values untouched if they are 0. If not, a certain amount is added (here +- 1 %). Later on, I combine this data set with the original data set and have my oversampled data.frame.

```r
# add percentage of noise to non-zero values in numerical columns
noised_copies <- train_oversampled %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "rowname") %>%
  filter(grepl("\\.", row.names(train_oversampled))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_if(~ is.numeric(.), ~ if_else(. == 0, 0,. + (. * flip() * 0.01 ))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "rowname")
# combine original and oversampled, noised data set
train_noised <- rbind(noised_copies, train_set)
```

I assume there are faster ways using e.g. data.table, but it was already tough work to get this code running and I have no idea how to improve its performance.

---

EDIT:

The solution is working perfectly fine with fixed values, but called within a for loop I receive "Error in paste(Sample, n, sep = ".") : object 'Sample' not found"

Code to replicate:

```r
library(data.table)

train_set <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(0, 10)), 
  y = c(0:9), 
  z = c(rep("Factor1", 10)))

# changing the row name to avoid confusion with "Sample"
row.names(train_set) <- c(paste("Observation", c(1:nrow(train_set)), sep = "_"))
train_list <- list(aa = train_set, bb = train_set, cc = train_set)

for(current_table in train_list) {
  setDT(current_table, keep.rownames="Sample")
  cols <- names(current_table)[sapply(current_table, is.numeric)]
  noised_copies <- lapply(c(1,2), function(n) {
    copy(current_table)[,
      c("Sample", cols) := c(.(paste(Sample, n, sep=".")), 
        .SD * sample(c(-1.01, 1.01), .N*ncol(.SD), TRUE)),
      .SDcols=cols]
  })
train_noised <- rbindlist(c(noised_copies, list(train_set)), use.names=FALSE)
# As this is an example, I did not write anything to actually 
# store the results, so I have to remove the object
rm(train_noised)
}
```

Any ideas why the column `Sample` can't be found now?

Comment: This might help https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-alternatives-to-rowwise/8071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more vectorized approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(train_set, keep.rownames="Sample")
cols <- names(train_set)[sapply(train_set, is.numeric)]
noised_copies <- lapply(c(1,2), function(n) {
    copy(train_set)[,
        c("Sample", cols) := c(.(paste(Sample, n, sep=".")), 
            .SD * sample(c(-1.01, 1.01), .N*ncol(.SD), TRUE)),
        .SDcols=cols]
})
train_noised <- rbindlist(c(noised_copies, list(train_set)), use.names=FALSE)
```

With data.table version >= 1.12.9, you can pass `is.numeric` directly to `.SDcols` argument and maybe a shorter way (e.g. `(.SD)` or `names(.SD)`) to pass to the left hand side of `:=`

---

address OP's updated post:

The issue is that although each `data.frame` within the list is converted to a `data.table`, the `train_list` is not updated. You can update the list with a left bind before the `for` loop:

```
library(data.table)

train_set <- data.frame(
    x = c(rep(0, 10)), 
    y = c(0:9), 
    z = c(rep("Factor1", 10)))

# changing the row name to avoid confusion with "Sample"
row.names(train_set) <- c(paste("Observation", c(1:nrow(train_set)), sep = "_"))
train_list <- list(aa = train_set, bb = copy(train_set), cc = copy(train_set))

train_list <- lapply(train_list, setDT, keep.rownames="Sample")

for(current_table in train_list) {
    cols <- names(current_table)[sapply(current_table, is.numeric)]
    noised_copies <- lapply(c(1,2), function(n) {
        copy(current_table)[,
            c("Sample", cols) := c(.(paste(Sample, n, sep=".")),
                .SD * sample(c(-1.01, 1.01), .N*ncol(.SD), TRUE)),
            .SDcols=cols]
    })
    train_noised <- rbindlist(c(noised_copies, train_list), use.names=FALSE)
    # As this is an example, I did not write anything to actually
    # store the results, so I have to remove the object
    rm(train_noised)
}
```

Comment: That looks really great. I'm trying to understand the syntax and I think I can adjust this to work as a function! But is there a way to keep the `row.names` and use modified `row.names` for the copies so I can track where which copy stems from?

Comment: That is of course absolutely fine. I changed to `setDT(train_set, keep.rownames = "Sample")` and in the `rbindlist` call I used `use.names = TRUE`, but now the names in `Sample` are identical across the replicates, so I can't turn it into a DF with this column as `row.names`. Something like `Sample_1` for the original and `Sample_1.1` and `Sample_1.2` for the two copies would be perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I used `setDF(train_noised, rownames = train_noised$Sample); train_noised$Sample <- NULL` to get everything back to the input format. Thank you!

Comment: In data.table lingo, we usually use train_noised[, Sample := NULL] to delete a column by reference

Comment: I'm sorry I have another problem: running this code works fine, but from within a function or for loop I get `Error in paste(Sample, n, sep = ".") : object 'Sample' not found`. I have no idea how to fix this, as the column was just defined in the same line of code, or? So it shouldn't be a problem of function scope?

Comment: I have edited the question and added code to reproduce the error

Comment: So, I had to ask one more question (see Linked questions) but now it works. I would like to mention that at least based on my intention the code to add the noise should rather be `.SD + .SD * sample(c(-0.01, 0.01)` instead of `.SD * sample(c(-1.01, 1.01)`. Thank you so much for your help, it runs way faster now!

Comment: @crazysantaclaus i think using addition will result in changes to your zero values. i interpreted your code as perturbing a 1% of non-zero values

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will check that. But right now I would argue that if `.SD == 0`, than `0 + 0 * 0.01` stays 0, right? But I first need to check if I read the data.table syntax correctly ;-)

Comment: @crazysantaclaus oops my bad it should be `.SD * sample(c(0.99, 1.01)` instead so that we dont even need to check the `.SD==0` condition saving some time

Comment: I checked my data and it looks like `.SD + .SD * sample(c(-0.01, 0.01)` is doing the job fine, no zero values are changed. In addition, I'm not actually using fixed values but use it in a function as `.SD + .SD * sample(c(-noise, noise)`

Comment: @crazysantaclaus sure as long as it works for you. i was being minimalist in removing that `+`