# lapply data.table setDT in nested lists does not work or is not idempotent?

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a nested list of data frames and I want to perform actions only on a specific data frame item named "train_set"

```r
library(data.table)

train_set <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(2, 10)), 
  y = c(0:9), 
  z = c(rep("Factor1", 10)))

test_set <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(1, 12)), 
  y = c(0:11), 
  z = c(rep("Factor2", 12)))

row.names(train_set) <- c(paste("Observation", c(1:nrow(train_set)), sep = "_"))
row.names(test_set) <- c(paste("Observation", c(1:nrow(test_set)), sep = "_"))

top_list <- list(
  aa = list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set), 
  bb = list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set), 
  cc = list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set)
)
```

the goal is to replicate rows in the train_set, add a little bit of noise and name them accordingly. Finally I want to return a list which has the same structure as the input list
but contains the modified train_set tables instead of the original ones.
As my dplyr code for these actions was quite slow, I got help here to increase performance by using data.table
[Speeding up dplyr pipe including checks with mutate_if and if_else on larger tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719172/speeding-up-dplyr-pipe-including-checks-with-mutate-if-and-if-else-on-larger-tab/59727178?noredirect=1#comment105650210_59727178)

However, in order to use data.table I have to convert these specific data.frames to data.tables.
The important thing is that I keep the row.names as column "Sample", as I need the names.

```r
# does not work on all elements, not run
# top_list <- lapply(top_list, function(next_level) lapply(next_level, setDT, keep.rownames = "Sample"))
```

I tried nested lapply and for loops to change either train_set, the whole list or both train and test_set to DT, as in the answer above it was mentioned that the list has to be updated. But I can't get it to work for this nested list. The code seems to work for the first iteration but not afterwards. Does anyone know how I can turn all these DF to DT and get the code
below running?

```r
result_list <- list()
counter <- 0
for (split_table in top_list) {
  counter <- counter +1
  current_name <- names(top_list)[counter]
  train_tmp <- split_table$train_set
  test_tmp <- split_table$test_set
  print(current_name)
  print(train_tmp)

  # either here or earlier turn DF into DT, but keep row.names
  setDT(train_tmp, keep.rownames = "Sample")
  print(train_tmp)  # get's ignored in the first iteration?
  # The row names are still present for the first iteration with item "aa"
  cols <- names(train_tmp)[sapply(train_tmp, is.numeric)]
  # this is the function to copy each row two times, add 10 % noise to each numeric column 
  # and append the Sample name with the copy number
  noised_copies <- lapply(c(1,2), function(n) {
    copy(train_tmp)[,
      # here we get the error as we need the column "Sample" to adjust the names of the replicated rows
      c("Sample", cols) := c(.(paste(Sample, n, sep=".")), 
        .SD * sample(c(-1.01, 1.01), .N*ncol(.SD), TRUE)),
      .SDcols=cols]
  })
  # combine original table and table with replicates
  train_noised <- rbindlist(c(noised_copies, list(train_tmp)), use.names = FALSE)
  # turn back into DF and add to result list
  setDF(train_noised, rownames = train_noised$Sample)
  train_noised$Sample <- NULL
  result_list[[current_name]] <- list(train_set = train_noised, test_set = test_tmp)
}
result_list
# it is important to have a clean workspace after each try
rm(top_list)
```

Comment: i would suggest working with a large data.table than list of lists of data.tables. `rbindlist(unlist(top_list, recursive=FALSE), use.names=FALSE, idcol="Table")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled a bit getting lapply to work too. I could get it to turn the data frames into data tables, but it refused to keep the row names.

I found a simple double loop works. It's probably making copies of the data frames before overwriting them, so I don't know if this will be fast enough for your needs. It seems to take about 6 milliseconds on your data using my machine.

```r
for(i in 1:3) 
  for(j in 1:2) 
    top_list[[i]][[j]] <- as.data.table(top_list[[i]][[j]], keep.rownames = "Sample")
```

This gives

```r
top_list
#> $`aa`
#> $`aa`$`train_set`
#>             Sample x y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 2 0 Factor1
#>  2:  Observation_2 2 1 Factor1
#>  3:  Observation_3 2 2 Factor1
#>  4:  Observation_4 2 3 Factor1
#>  5:  Observation_5 2 4 Factor1
#>  6:  Observation_6 2 5 Factor1
#>  7:  Observation_7 2 6 Factor1
#>  8:  Observation_8 2 7 Factor1
#>  9:  Observation_9 2 8 Factor1
#> 10: Observation_10 2 9 Factor1
#> 
#> $`aa`$test_set
#>             Sample x  y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 1  0 Factor2
#>  2:  Observation_2 1  1 Factor2
#>  3:  Observation_3 1  2 Factor2
#>  4:  Observation_4 1  3 Factor2
#>  5:  Observation_5 1  4 Factor2
#>  6:  Observation_6 1  5 Factor2
#>  7:  Observation_7 1  6 Factor2
#>  8:  Observation_8 1  7 Factor2
#>  9:  Observation_9 1  8 Factor2
#> 10: Observation_10 1  9 Factor2
#> 11: Observation_11 1 10 Factor2
#> 12: Observation_12 1 11 Factor2
#> 
#> 
#> $bb
#> $bb$`train_set`
#>             Sample x y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 2 0 Factor1
#>  2:  Observation_2 2 1 Factor1
#>  3:  Observation_3 2 2 Factor1
#>  4:  Observation_4 2 3 Factor1
#>  5:  Observation_5 2 4 Factor1
#>  6:  Observation_6 2 5 Factor1
#>  7:  Observation_7 2 6 Factor1
#>  8:  Observation_8 2 7 Factor1
#>  9:  Observation_9 2 8 Factor1
#> 10: Observation_10 2 9 Factor1
#> 
#> $bb$test_set
#>             Sample x  y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 1  0 Factor2
#>  2:  Observation_2 1  1 Factor2
#>  3:  Observation_3 1  2 Factor2
#>  4:  Observation_4 1  3 Factor2
#>  5:  Observation_5 1  4 Factor2
#>  6:  Observation_6 1  5 Factor2
#>  7:  Observation_7 1  6 Factor2
#>  8:  Observation_8 1  7 Factor2
#>  9:  Observation_9 1  8 Factor2
#> 10: Observation_10 1  9 Factor2
#> 11: Observation_11 1 10 Factor2
#> 12: Observation_12 1 11 Factor2
#> 
#> 
#> $cc
#> $cc$`train_set`
#>             Sample x y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 2 0 Factor1
#>  2:  Observation_2 2 1 Factor1
#>  3:  Observation_3 2 2 Factor1
#>  4:  Observation_4 2 3 Factor1
#>  5:  Observation_5 2 4 Factor1
#>  6:  Observation_6 2 5 Factor1
#>  7:  Observation_7 2 6 Factor1
#>  8:  Observation_8 2 7 Factor1
#>  9:  Observation_9 2 8 Factor1
#> 10: Observation_10 2 9 Factor1
#> 
#> $cc$test_set
#>             Sample x  y       z
#>  1:  Observation_1 1  0 Factor2
#>  2:  Observation_2 1  1 Factor2
#>  3:  Observation_3 1  2 Factor2
#>  4:  Observation_4 1  3 Factor2
#>  5:  Observation_5 1  4 Factor2
#>  6:  Observation_6 1  5 Factor2
#>  7:  Observation_7 1  6 Factor2
#>  8:  Observation_8 1  7 Factor2
#>  9:  Observation_9 1  8 Factor2
#> 10: Observation_10 1  9 Factor2
#> 11: Observation_11 1 10 Factor2
#> 12: Observation_12 1 11 Factor2
```

Comment: I will try this on my real data. I had the same thought but was unable to assign the for loop's output in a way that kept the list structure

Comment: I think this actually works. There might be faster implementations, but this is now definitely fast enough for my needs compared to my previous `dplyr` version. I adjusted the code to `for (i in c(1:length(top_list)) for (j in c(1))` to generalize the outer loop and only adjust the first table (the `train_set`) in the inner loop. I would still like to know what is wrong with the `lapply` call, though?

Comment: I didn’t try assigning back within lapply - you could try that. I use lapply a lot, but I think the loop is cleaner than a nested lapply here because the call is a one liner, so you don’t need brackets